# Norm of the resolvent and inequalities

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

I am considering the equation

$$ \lambda q- \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2} q}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}=g, $$
where $g\in L^p(X)$ and $q\in W^{2,p}(X)$. If, I know that
$$
\mid \mid \lambda (\lambda I- \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2} }{\mathrm{d} x^{2}})^{-1} \mid \mid
\leq M
$$
How can I conclude that
$$
\left\|\lambda q\right\|_{L^{p}(X)}+\left\|q\right\|_{W^{2,p}(X)} \leqslant C\|g\|_{L^{p}(X)} ?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^{2}}{\mathrm{d} x^{2}}$. Then $q=R(\lambda,A)g$. It follows that
$$\begin{aligned}
\left\|\lambda q\right\|_{L^{p}(X)}+\left\|q\right\|_{W^{2,p}(X)} & \le\|\lambda R(\lambda,A)g\|_{L^{p}(X)} + \|R(\lambda,A)g\|_{D(A)}\\
& \le M  \|g\|_{L^{p}(X)} + (\frac{M}{\lambda}\|g\|_{L^{p}(X)}+ \|AR(\lambda,A)g\|_{L^{p}(X)}) \\
&= M  \|g\|_{L^{p}(X)} + (\frac{M}{\lambda}\|g\|_{L^{p}(X)}+ \|\lambda R(\lambda,A)g - g\|_{L^{p}(X)})\\
& \le (1+M \frac{2\lambda +1}{\lambda}) \|g\|_{L^{p}(X)}.
\end{aligned}$$